# How to get data from table if username and password correct or return only text?

Tags: postgresql, function

I am new to database I am working on PostgreSQL and below I am creating function for check user login authentication. what I want that I want get user detail if username and password correct else I want to return only text that "invalid username and password". I am not sure that is this a correct way of writing queries in function? How can I achieve this ?

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (f1 varchar(100), f2 varchar(100),f3 varchar(100) );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_login (username varchar, pasword varchar)
RETURNS  my_type
as $$
declare
    cnt integer;
    msg varchar;
result_record my_type;
begin
select count(*) into cnt from FIELD_USER where user_name = username and password = pasword;
if cnt>0
then
select user_name,mobile,'success' into result_record.f1,result_record.f2,result_record.f3 from field_user;
else
select user_name,mobile,'failure' into result_record.f1,result_record.f2,result_record.f3 from field_user where user_name = username and password = pasword;
end if;
return result_record;
end;$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Do you want to return user information in JSON format?

Comment: Yes I want get user detail if username password is correct. Otherwise i want to get only string like "invalid usrrname and password".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement. Please give the below code a try.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_login (username varchar, pasword varchar)
RETURNS "pg_catalog"."json" AS $BODY$
as $$
declare

    user_cursor refcursor;
    user_row record;

BEGIN

    open user_cursor for select * from FIELD_USER where user_name = username and password = pasword;;
    FETCH user_cursor INTO user_row;
    IF FOUND THEN
        return row_to_json(user_row);
    ELSE
         return '{"msg":"Email or Password is invalid"}';
    END IF;

END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Please note: A postgresql function can only return value of a single type. You can not return value of different types based on conditions.

Comment: `RETURNS my_type`?

Comment: Updated the return type as JSON

Answer (score 0):

Your third `SELECT` with `'failure'` in it will set `user_name` and `mobile` to NULL because the query has no result row. Is that what you want?

Also, your second `SELECT` statement seems to be lacking a `WHERE` clause.

You could be more efficient and use only a single query if you check the [`FOUND`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) variable:

```
SELECT user_name, mobile, 'failure'
   INTO result_record.f1, result_record.f2, result_record.f3
   FROM field_user
   WHERE user_name = username
     AND password = pasword;

IF FOUND THEN
   result_record.f3 := 'success';
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but if I am executing my function with correct username and password then i am getting result like this - (moin,1234567898,success) but if I execute function with wrong  username and password then i want only result like this - (failure). That's what I want to do.

Comment: Well, you cannot, because your result type has three fields. So you can only get something similar to `(NULL, NULL, 'failure')`.

Comment: Yes you are right. But i want only failure so how can I achieve this ?

Comment: The message is clear: if `result.f3` is `failure` and `result.f1` is NULL, you didn't find anything. How you format this for the user is a different thing that should be independent of the data structure returned by the function.